# How to limit the result coming from API in IONIC 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on a project where I have to make a HTTP call in which I get a array of result whose length is 60+ and it takes a lot of time to load.

How can I limit the result & display the list of 20 array at first load and on scrolling down the other 20 and so on?

This is my .ts file

```
    getUserList() {
        this.showLoader();
        this.authService.getData(this.search, "search")
          .then((result) => {
            let yourString = typeof result == 'object' && result["_body"] ? result["_body"] : [];
            let res = yourString.substring(1, yourString.length - 1);
            this.hideLoader();
            this.response = JSON.parse(res);
            console.log(this.response);
          }, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
```

this is the console.log(this.response)

[image]

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to customize your API in such a way that it returns result in each scrolling . Let me show an example code. Hope this will help you once the API Upgraded,

### Mention (ionScrollEnd) in Template

```
<ion-content (ionScrollEnd)="logScrolling($event)">
```

### Ts file

Declare variable as current_page = 0;

```
logScrolling(event)
{
 this.book_details();
}
book_details()
{
sendData= {'name':'Test'}
this.myservice.online_service(this.funcName, sendData).subscribe(response => {
    if ( response.status === 'success' && response.data.length > 0) {
      this.bookDetails = this.bookDetails.concat(response.data);
      ++this.current_page;
}
```

Comment: Customize your api in such a way that it accept current_page value from user and returns response according to each current_page value. You can set 10 records for each page ,like that as your wish

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control from ionic side. But if you able to modify api then you can create an api which can return specific number of data. For example in first request api returns 0 to 10 records. Then made second request to get 11 to 20 records and so on. To achieve this functionality you can use [Ionic InfiniteScroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/).

Comment: Yes i exactly want this. I tried Infinite Scroll but it load all 71 result 1st then again the same 71 result